# RESTful security authorization

Tags: java, javascript, security, rest, authorization

I have an application which is wrote with JS frameworks and it makes REST request to RESTful service which I wrote. The problem is that I want to put an authorization. I found OAuth 1.0a and OAuth 2 for using them for that purpose. How can I make a security authorization layer in my REST with public and private key for an example if the client is JS based application ( browser application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at the [implicit flow in OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.2) which is specifically geared towards clients running JavaScript in the browser.

It's not using asymmetric encryption directly in JavaScript. If you want to do that, you could look at the [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your REST service on a server with SSL based client authentication. [Here](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2012/07/10/enabling-ssl-communication-and-client-certificate-authentication-between-apache-web-) is how a tutorial on how you can do it on tomcat for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I want to validate the credentials from the database. So if a user want to use the REST functionality he must be register in the database.

Comment: Why don't you go for a login/password based authentication then?

Comment: You can combine HTTPS on your server with login/password authentication. It will be as secure as default gmail authentication ;)

Comment: I like this idea http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/ but I didn't get the thing with the time stamp and the HMAC hash

Comment: Is there some framework for Java which provide REST authentication?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. If you have integrated the Spring stack, Spring Security is a good choice.

Comment: The official documentation is a good starting point: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/

Comment: A specific project is available if you are still interested in Oauth: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/